# In what media the speed of light is slower than the speed of radio waves, if any?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction, dispersion, radio-frequency

In what media the speed of visible light is slower than the speed of radio waves, if any?
Particles can be faster than visible light, but other electromagnetic waves?

Comment: Light which require no medium travels slower in denser medium, this is because there are more particles in its way. Sound waves which requires a medium travels faster in denser medium, this is because there are more particles, the molecules can bump into each other quicker.

Comment: Is it important that light be slower than radio in general, or is it acceptable if only a narrow band of radio waves propagates faster than light? (Or that only a narrow band of optical frequencies propagates slower than RF)

Comment: Yes, narrow band is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the index of refraction of most materials increases as frequency increases. This is called *normal dispersion*.

However, when there is a resonant behavior in the material, there will be a region of *anomalous dispersion* where the index decreases over a relatively narrow band of increasing frequencies. And this effect is strong enough that over very wide bands, the overall trend is for the index to decrease with increasing frequencies:

[image]
([Image source](https://www.brown.edu/research/labs/mittleman/sites/brown.edu.research.labs.mittleman/files/uploads/lecture08_0.pdf), slide 16)

This means that it is very unlikely that you will find a natural material with higher index (slower propagation of light) at RF frequencies than at optical frequencies, unless you can find a material with no resonance over the whole IR band spanning from the microwave RF frequencies to the ones we normally call "optical frequencies">

However, for a specific combination of RF and optical frequencies, you might find a material that is near resonance at one of those frequencies, leading to either an abnormally low index at your RF frequency or an abnormally high index at your optical frequency, and obtain the effect you want (but, be aware that the anomalous dispersion region is also a region of high absorption).

You might also be able to construct a [meta-material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial) (basically a periodic structure of two or more different materials) with a resonance at one of your two frequencies, as demonstrated [here](https://phys.org/news/2015-01-metamaterial-prism-reverse-rainbow.html).

Comment: Perfect, thank you!